# How to create a new list everytime the first element of a list is repeated?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

How to create a new list everytime the first element of a list is repeated? For example:

```
list1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 9, 4, 7, 8, 1]

newlist1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 2]

newlist2 = [1, 9, 4, 7, 8, 1]
```

Comment: Are you familiar with two-dimensional lists?

Comment: It is unlikely that you will get a good answer that includes a bunch of individual dynamic variables like `newlist1`, `newlist2`, etc. You should be making a list of lists and then you can access them with `newlists[0]`, `newlists[1]`, etc.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the last element of `list1` will be equal to the first element of the last sublist?

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this is with a generator. Create a list and append elements to it in a loop. When the condition is met, yield the sublists and start again. Note, this will ignore values at the end if they don't end with the same value they start with. If that's not the desired behavior you can yield one more time with the partial sublist after the loop:

```
def partition_on_first(l):
    sub_list = []
    for n in l:
        sub_list.append(n)
        if len(sub_list) > 1 and sub_list[0] == n:
            yield sub_list
            sub_list = []
        
        
    
list1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 9, 4, 7, 8, 1]
list(partition_on_first(list1))  
# [[2, 3, 4, 5, 2], [1, 9, 4, 7, 8, 1]]

# case with "left-overs":
list1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 9, 4, 7, 8, 1, 100, 101, 102]

list(partition_on_first(list1))
# ignores last three values
# [[2, 3, 4, 5, 2], [1, 9, 4, 7, 8, 1]]
```

Comment: Yay, generators FTW!